# Scale video without keeping aspect ratio in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, scale

I want to make a video 'wide', so the width is increased and the height stays the same as of the input image. I use the following command: `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf scale="1000:200" output.mp4`. It just does not work. The most interesting thing that it works with png images but not with videos.
Example: video before:[image]

After: [image]

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: a shot in the dark - but as far as I know, you don't need the quotation-marks when defining the scale. Instead, try: scale=1000:200

Comment: @Gyan https://pastebin.com/vm68342n

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen I tried, it did not work

Comment: @BakhanovA. Huh, was worth a try.

Comment: I found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346707/ffmpeg-scaling-not-working-for-video, just add `sar=1`

Comment: surreal... I found this question because I, too, was trying to make a "wide putin"-styled video, and had tried using scale in this way. I used "1000:300", but, wow... that's really similar

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by setting the attached SAR (Sample/Storage Aspect Ratio):

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf scale=1000:200,setsar=1 output.mp4
```